# Permission denied when trying to compile own shell in linux, what can I do?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I know this question was asked before, but I already tried to use chmod or sudo and it's still not working. So the thing is this:

I have bash on ubuntu on windows installed on my windows 10. I wrote my own shell in terminal but I did something wrong and deleted days of work by accident... So to be sure I started and wrote it again in codeblocks and just copied the c file in the directory so that i can see the file when i do the command ls.

The problem is when I try to do this:

```
gcc -o shell shell.c
```

I get

> cc1: fatal error: shell.c: Permission denied

What can I do?

When I type `ls -ld . shell.c shell` I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 0 Lightning Lightning   512 Jan 16 23:35 .
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root      19576 Jan 16 23:35 shell
---------- 1 Lightning Lightning 17310 Jan 16 23:35 shell.c
```

And to clarify as a lot of you understand that I used sudo and that the shell file is the problem. It is not! Sudo solved my problem (I understand that it's not the best solution, that's why I'm trying to find another one), but I had the problem before I used sudo. And when I use the code:

```
 gcc shell.c
```

I still get permission denied!

Comment: What does this question have to do with `bash`?

Comment: I'm a beginner, I don't understand a lot of things, so I don't know what my problem is related to... so sorry if it doesn't have anything to do with bash.

Comment: What are the permissions of `shell.c` and the current directory? Who's their owner and are you logged in as that user? Does `shell` already exist and, if so, what are its permissions and owner? When you say that have "already tried to use chmod or sudo", what exactly have you tried?

Comment: maybe `shell` is still running and therefore file is locked? You should also start using version control systems such as mercurial to avoid "deleted days of work by accident".

Comment: Step 1: **Install a version control system** so you can check in your work as you go and any disasters are short-term, you can just pull down your code if you ever mess up or revert if you ever break it too badly to fix it.

Comment: (a) Copy the entire command and output and paste it into your question. (b) Check whether `shell` exists; execute `file shell` and `ls -ld shell`. (Consider that it might be a directory, not a regular file.) (c) Create a new file `x.c` and try `gcc -o x x.c` and report the results. (d) If (c) fails, try that in a different directory.

Comment: Well, shell.c is made directly in codeblocks and saved, so I guess it has normal permissions. The folder is C:\Users\Clevo\AppData\Local\lxss\home\user... i don't know the permissions of it, but I guess it's ok if i could copy in it. I tried chmod u+x filename.c and the equivalent with sudo. Shell is not still running. Thanks for the advice to prevent disasters :D

Comment: tried everything at (a)... shell does not exist, just the shell.c i put there. I tried with x.c and it works... it compiles a simple hello world program without any problem. But that was made in shell with nano, if I make it outside the shell, in codeblocks, I get the same error.

Comment: Try `gcc -o x shell.c`. If that works, try `mv x shell`.

Comment: nevermind... I found a solution with this... I tried to modify the permissions of the file with sudo, but I didn't try to compile it with sudo, that worked, and now the shell is created and I can run it with ./shell command... Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Using sudo to compile *anything* is a bad idea. Instead, you should fix permissions such that you don't *need* sudo to access your own files.

Comment: You should only need to use `sudo` to install your final fully debugged (for now— until you find the next bug) shell. Until then, you should be inning the compiler and the shell-under-debug as an ordinary user and not use elevated privileges (`sudo`) at all.

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question, it should be posted as an answer. But you shouldn't need to use `sudo` to compile files in your own directory.

Comment: Hang on, did you literally type `gcc -o shell shell.c,` _with the comma_?

Comment: @zwol no, no comma

Comment: @Charles Duffy I guess it's not the best solution, but I really needed it to work, because I had to test it and submit it an hour ago for a school project, so I was low on time and any solution was good. I still don't know what I should do for it to work without sudo, if anyone has an idea, I would be grateful!

Comment: You'd need to provide more details. Editing the output of `ls -ld . shell.c shell` into the question would be a place to start.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy done

Comment: So, there are two problems here. One is that `root` owns the output file; the other is that absolutely nobody has permission to read the input file (except root, which is exempt from the permission system). The easy answer is to just delete the output file, and to fix permissions on the input file with something like `chmod 644 shell.c` (no `sudo` needed).

Comment: (and btw, as Barmar said -- don't edit solutions into questions; instead, use the button to add an answer to add an answer as a separate item. It's only when you've accepted an answer that your question will be marked solved).

Comment: @JohnSmith I have revised my answer in light of the new information you have given us.

Comment: The problem isn't the difference between "Permission" and "permission". The problem is that the actual error message almost certainly referred to `shell.c`, but the version of that message in the question omitted that information. It's the difference between "`cc1: fatal error: Permission denied`" and `"cc1: fatal error: shell.c: Permission denied"`.

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah, I have deleted my comment, I'm too tired, I saw it way too late, sorry

Comment: BTW, with respect to using "Codeblocks" or other native Windows applications to edit files -- see the official Microsoft blog article titled [Do not change Linux files using Windows apps or tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cc1: fatal error: permission denied
```

Are you *certain* that this is the exact text of the error message?  Could it have instead been this?

```
cc1: fatal error: shell.c: permission denied
```

Every single word counts in Unix-style error messages.  The error message you *said* you got doesn't refer to `shell.c` at all.  It seems to be reporting a permissions problem affecting `cc1`, which is an internal component of the compiler, which is why the previous version of this answer said "your installation of GCC is broken".  But if that were your problem, you would not be able to compile *anything*, and you say you can compile other things besides `shell.c`.

The modified error message, on the other hand, is reporting a permissions problem *detected* by `cc1` but *affecting* `shell.c`, which is consistent with the claim that only `shell.c` can't be compiled, and is also consistent with your `ls` output:

```
---------- 1 Lightning Lightning 17310 Jan 16 23:35 shell.c
```

That leading string of dashes stands for access "mode" 000, which means "cannot be read, written, or executed by *anyone*, except `root`."  (One of `root`'s many privileges is that it bypasses all access controls.)

If this is indeed your problem, running the commands

```
chmod 644 shell.c
sudo rm -f shell
```

from the directory containing `shell.c` should make a subsequent `gcc shell.c -o shell` work.  These commands deserve a little explanation: `chmod` is the Unix command to change access permissions. `chmod 644` sets the permissions to `-rw-r--r--` (read and write by owning user, read-only by all others), which is almost always the right set of permissions for ordinary files.  (You can also say `chmod u=rw,go=r shell.c`, but once you get a little practice with them, you will find the octal permissions easier to read and write!)  It's also necessary to delete `shell`, as `root`, because currently `root` owns that file and the compiler running as an ordinary user won't be allowed to overwrite it.

The remaining question is: how on earth did your `shell.c` get its mode set to 000 in the first place?  That is an extremely bizarre thing to have happen.  My best guess would be that your "codeblocks" editor is a native Windows program instead of a Ubuntu-for-Windows program and it isn't interacting properly with the nested Unix environment, but there are several other possibilities, and I don't think I can help you any further.

Comment: What is strange is that with other programms made in shell with nano it works. But, with programms made in codeblocks and then copied in that directory, those don't work.

Comment: OP has since reported that `gcc -o x x.c` works. So the compiler installation is not outright broken. That makes me wonder if there is some bug where it internally attempts to execute some `shell` command, which fails if there is a `shell` file in the current directory.

Comment: I think the problem is simply that the output file `shell` was owned by `root`, so he couldn't write to it.

Comment: @Barmar Inability to write to the output file should have produced a different error message.

Comment: You're right. When I try that on my Mac, I get "ld: can't write output file".

Comment: Shouldn't need `sudo rm` -- if you own the directory, you can delete files no matter who owns them.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I'm sorry, I'm a beginner, I did not realise the difference from p to P is so big. And yes, indeed, my codeblocks editor is a native Windows program.

Comment: ... uh, the important difference is that one of them says "shell.c" in it and the other doesn't ...

Comment: Pff, I'm blind... I'm sorry, haven't sleeped in a while, got a lot of projects... I was so sure that shell.c was not in there, but indeed it was, even when I read it from the terminal... I'm really sorry I wasted your time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JohnSmith You didn't waste my time. You provided an ideal jumping-off point for me to write an answer about why it's so important to read every word of an error message.

Comment: @JohnSmith Also, a word of friendly advice from someone who was once a sleep-deprived student himself: get more sleep! It has been scientifically proven that a full eight hours of sleep every night will help your grades _more_ than any extra homework/study time you gain by not sleeping.

Comment: Thank you! I will try :D

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: My answer was based on incomplete information. I believe [zwol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48289314/827263) is the correct one.

When you made the mistake of running:

```
sudo gcc -o shell shell.c
```

it created an executable file named `shell`, owned by `root`. When you then tried again without the `sudo` command:

```
gcc -o shell shell.c
```

it tried to overwrite the `shell` executable file, but it failed because you don't have permission to clobber a file owned by `root`. (Permissions are more complex than that, but that's the general idea.)

Don't use `sudo` to compile. In general, don't use `sudo`, or root access of any kind, to do anything that doesn't actually need to be done by the `root` account. (You might need to use `sudo` to *install* something to a location outside your home directory tree.)

Comment: I understand that sudo should not be used, but the thing is I did not used sudo before and I got that error. I used sudo to solve that problem! I did not get the error after I used sudo. And like I said in some comments, simple `gcc shell.c` is not working... the problem is not with the shell file...

Comment: @JohnSmith: Then you haven't given us enough information to solve the problem. The `ls -ld` output you show us is clearly from *after* you tried the `sudo` command. Using `sudo` likely didn't solve your problem, it just worked around it. If `gcc -o shell shell.c` gave you a "permission denied" error, then you probably had a file named `shell` that you didn't have permission to overwrite. If you had that problem before using `sudo`, then there's no way for us to tell how it happened.

Comment: Try removing the `shell` file (`sudo rm shell`) rerun the `ls` command, then run `gcc -o shell shell.c`. If that fails, show us the output of the `ls` and `gcc` commands.

Comment: If the problem is with the shell file... why `gcc shell.c` still gives me that error? It should work and I should be able to run it with `./a.out`.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I don't know. Maybe you also have an existing `a.out` file in that directory? Please try what I asked you to try.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I see from more recent comments that I missed something critical in your `ls` output. Your `shell.c` file has `000` permissions, so nothing can read it. As somebody else mentioned, the compiler error message would have referred to the name of the input file. **Always** copy-and-paste error messages. A seemingly minor omission like this can lead everyone on a wild goose chase. If we had seen "`cc1: fatal error: shell.c: Permission denied`", we could probably have answered your question much sooner.

Answer (score 0):

With you given command line option of `-o shell`, you are indicating that you want gcc to store the built output in a file named `shell`. From your directory listing, this file is owned by the owner.group combination `root.root`, and only the user `root` has write permissions to that file.

Assuming you are running `gcc` as the user `Lightning` (the owner of `shell.c`), then the error message is understandable: `gcc` does not have permission to overwrite the output file you've specified.

As a workaround, you should be able to specify a different output file such as `shell2` via `gcc -o shell2 shell.c` and it should produce the executable file `shell2`.

A longer term solution if you really want the executable to be named `shell` would be to delete the file `shell` or change its permissions such that other users can write to it (`chmod 777 shell`); either of these operations must be performed as the user `root`.

Comment: `chmod 777` is overkill; it allows any user on the system to modify the file. Just don't compile as root.

Comment: even if shell does not exist I still can't compile, I mean, even if I write `gcc shell.c` it still won't let me do it...

Comment: (I can't seem to figure out how to format a block of text as code; apologies)
It seems you would get a different error message, at least with `gcc` v6.3.0: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file shell: Permission denied`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Yes, I get the same error... and I don't mean the one in your second message, I don't get that...